# Why does VBA calculate different depending whether value is in an array or not?

Tags: excel, vba, range, double, mismatch

In Excel VBA, I have made a code to simulate some prices based on some parameter, but one of the parameters gives whole different simulation results, when it comes from an array rather than as a variable, which I cannot understand (values of "Copper" becomes way negative in multiple of the runs when using the array).

Version using array:

```
'Calculate Price Matrix
For j = 1 To Years
    'For each Commodity
    For i = 1 To N
        'Generate Correlated Brownian Motions
        For k = 1 To i
            dW(i) = dW(i) + A(i, k) * 0.5
        Next k

        'Calculate Price for year
        S(i) = Exp(-Lambda(i)) * S(i) + (1 - Exp(-Lambda(i))) * Mu(i) + Sigma(i) * Sqr((1 - Exp(-2 * Lambda(i))) / (2 * Lambda(i))) * dW(i)

        'Populate Price in Model
        Sheets("Prices").Cells(i + 1, j + 2).Value = S(i)
    Next i
Next j
```

Version using double:

```
'Calculate Price Matrix
For j = 1 To Years            
    'For each Commodity
    For i = 1 To N
        'Generate Correlated Brownian Motions
        dW = 0.5

        'Calculate Price for year
        S(i) = Exp(-Lambda(i)) * S(i) + (1 - Exp(-Lambda(i))) * Mu(i) + Sigma(i) * Sqr((1 - Exp(-2 * Lambda(i))) / (2 * Lambda(i))) * dW

        'Populate Price in Model
        Sheets("Prices").Cells(i + 1, j + 2).Value = S(i)
    Next i
Next j
```

As `A(1,1)=1` running the two codes should give the same result for `S(1)...` but it does not at all. I have even tried to change `dW(i) = dW(i) + A(i, k) * 0.5` simply to `dW(i) = 0.5`. But the results still differ. What can cause this issue?

Hope someone had the same issue before. Is it some kind of limitation in MS Excel?

Comment: Instead of 2 separate functions, just create a 1 element array in the "double" version and pass that to the one you say works.

Comment: Is `dW` perhaps defined as a function somewhere?  In VBA, array syntax and function syntax are indistinguishable unlike C++,Java,C#.

Comment: actually you need to post more code to be honest.  These are all the undefined variables `Dim j, i, Years, N, k, a(), dW(), Lambda(), S(), Mu(), Sigma()`

Comment: Please add all variable declarations into the question. Have a look at [mcve] and post a code that we can copy and execute to reproduce the issue. Therefore also add example data/values for the variables to illustrate and reproduce the issue.  And make sure you use `Option Explicit` so we can assume there are no typos in variable names.

Comment: I added the entire code below... sorry for the lack of information. I have not been asking questions here before ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the lack of information. Below is the full code using a range for dW()

```
Option Explicit
Sub SimulatePrices()
'Variables
    Dim Lambda() As Double
    Dim Sigma() As Double
    Dim Mu() As Double
    Dim Exp1() As Double
    Dim Exp2() As Double
    'Dim dW() As Double
    Dim A() As Double
    Dim S() As Double
    Dim i, j, k, N, Years As Long
'Define Ranges for Price Simulations
    Sheets("DataInput").Select
    N = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count - 1
    Sheets("Prices").Select
    Years = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, 2).End(xlToRight)).Columns.Count - 1

    ReDim Lambda(1 To N)
    ReDim Sigma(1 To N)
    ReDim Mu(1 To N)
    ReDim S(1 To N)

    ReDim dW(1 To N)
    ReDim A(1 To N, 1 To N)

'Populate Variable Matrices
    Sheets("DataInput").Select

    For i = 1 To N

        'Populate OUP Parmameters
        S(i) = Cells(i + 1, 5)
        Lambda(i) = Cells(i + 1, 2)
        Sigma(i) = Cells(i + 1, 4)
        Mu(i) = Cells(i + 1, 3)

        'Populate Cholesky Matrix
        For j = 1 To N
            A(i, j) = Cells(i + 13, j + 1).Value
        Next j

    Next i

'Calculate Price Matrix
    For j = 1 To Years

        'For each Commodity
        For i = 1 To N

            'Generate Correlated Brownian Motions
             For k = 1 To i
                dW(i) = dW(i) + A(i, k) * MSRndNorm

             Next k

            'Calculate Price for year
                S(i) = Exp(-Lambda(i)) * S(i) + (1 - Exp(-Lambda(i))) * Mu(i) + Sigma(i) * Sqr((1 - Exp(-2 * Lambda(i))) / (2 * Lambda(i))) * dW(i)
            'Populate Price in Model
                Sheets("Prices").Cells(i + 1, j + 2).Value = S(i)
        Next i
Next j
Sheets("Prices").Activate
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
End Sub

Function MSRndNorm() As Double
'Marsaglia-Bray modification of Box-Muller method
Dim U1, U2 As Double
Dim x As Double, y As Double
x = 1.1
While x > 1
U1 = Rnd()
U2 = Rnd()
U1 = 2 * U1 - 1
U2 = 2 * U2 - 1
x = U1 ^ 2 + U2 ^ 2
Wend
y = Sqr(-2 * Log(x) / x)
MSRndNorm = U1 * y
End Function
```